# Can't get Linux smartctl to show me disk health

Tags: linux, hard-drive, centos, raid

CentOS 7

I'm trying to use `smartctl` to show my disk info.

I have an Dell PowerEdge R720 with an H710P controller, running RAID 10.

When I run `df` in the Linux virtual machine, it says `/dev/loop0` is my primary drive.

I installed Centos on a container using proxmox so I'm assuming that's why it installed on `loop0` not `sda` or `sdb`.

Well when I run `smartctl -d megaraid,1 /dev/loop0` it just says failed no such device.

Output of `df`:

[image: output of df]

```
/root$ losetup -l
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE
/dev/loop0         0      0         1  0 /media/RAID10/images/104/vm-104-disk-1.raw
```

```
/root$ df /media/RAID10/images/104/vm-104-disk-1.raw
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1      959336516 254342164 656193024  28% /media/RAID10
```

Comment: That sounds like an odd setup... `/dev/loop0` is not actually a device, it's a "_loop device_". Try running `losetup -l`, and it should identify what the underlying device is in the `BACK-FILE` column.

Comment: The backfile just shows the path to where my virtual disk is installed. 

`/media/RAID10/images/104/vm-104-disk-1.raw`

Comment: Oh I see... what device / filesystem is `vm-104-disk-1.raw` on? Can the container "see" this device? Run `df /media/RAID10/images/104/vm-104-disk-1.raw` to find the owning filesystem. You'll probably have to run this on the host, not in the container.

Comment: I'm not sure if the container can see the device. 

the disk is on /dev/sdb. Its all a virtual environment.

Dell poweredge r720 has proxmox virtual environment installed on it. proxmox has 2 drives, sda and sdb. sda is my 250GB ssd that I installed proxmox onto and sdb is where I mounted my RAID 10 array. sdb is where I stored my centos virtual disk.

Comment: It's quite possible you won't be able to get anything out of `smartctl` without communicating with the host/proxmox... try running `smartctl` on `/dev/sdb` to find out. This could be due to proxmox (depending on how the storage is passed through), and it's also quite likely that the RAID controller will strip the ability from you too.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it doesn't look like you'll be able to get any decent S.M.A.R.T. data from your disks due to the RAID controller you're using. `smartmontools` has a list of [supported RAID controllers](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Supported_RAID-Controllers).

To me, this implies that 7xx controllers are not supported... but have you tried any other device IDs? See note #8: "*Please note that on some controllers device enumeration starts from 8 (use `-d megaraid,8` in such cases)*"

---

Additionally, within the virtual machine (container), you will be unable to access any S.M.A.R.T. data due to Proxmox's use of loop devices.

Proxmox does however apparently [include the `smartctl` utility](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Disk_Health_Monitoring), so you might be able to monitor the health of your non-RAID volumes. To do this, you'll have to log in to the host itself rather than a virtual machine.

---

This is a common issue with RAID controllers. Many have their own utilities for managing and health checks - I believe that the Dell / PERC (PowerEdge RAID Controller) utility is called `perccli`... though this answer mentions another and may get you on the right track.

[How to monitor the hard disk status behind Dell PERC H710 Raid Controller](https://serverfault.com/a/589166/405400).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, smartctl won't work on megaraid, but you can use MegaCLI.

The installation instructions can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/metajiji/cf859a7fc65a63690ecb208d11ea8407

After this you can run:

```
 MegaCli64 -PDList -aALL |grep flagged
```

to get return:

```
 Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No
```

By removing the |grep flagged from the command you can see the disk name and long listing of information. See also
https://blog.frehi.be/2011/09/12/megacli-useful-commands/